# ASP.Net MVC Session State Mangement - Cross Site Visit

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session

I would appreciate any help in the matter described below in detail. I have a background i ASP.Net webforms - and having been away from development for a number of years - I find it quite overwhelming to get back in the game and "upgrade" to MVC. I will however not surrender - so here I am asking questions.

I thought the best way to learn it - was to take an existing web application (webforms) and migrate it - rewriting it from ground up. This is coming along fine - however I would like some insights/help on patterns for session management. I never used viewstate in webforms (but implemented quite a lot of statemaintenance logic to provide better  userexperiences) - so the lack of viewstate is not the problem.

In my webforms application I implemented the following - which has proven to be very succesfull - at least from feedback from users.

1. All session variables were defined in SQL table - (one row for each user). For example the chosen colorscheme.
2. On Session start - following successful login - all sessionvariables are loaded from tables and put (back) into session variables.
3. User navigates site and makes different choices (manipulates state variables) - for example chooses number of items he/she would like to view in list views.
4. On Session end - (timeout or abandoned) the variables are put back to SQL server.

This will preserve state across visits to the site. As it is an intranet application with various pages carrying rich UI - it has proven to be quite a good "application-like" experience for the users.

Now - how could this be implemented in MVC? Where is the best place to put the code - without messing up separation of concerns and other considerations. What about EF - does this come in handy here - as a given users list of session variables is actually a row in a database table.

I have come across different posts and various opinions - but I can't seem to find a proven pattern.

Any insights are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

MVC doesn't actually change anything about the way that Session state works.  All of the things that you mentioned above should still work even in the latest release of ASP .NET MVC.

That said, the particular problem you are trying to solve sounds more like a User Profile Provider rather than a "Session"